# Как сделать мультиязычный сервис?

Tags: golang

Какой подход и либы выбрать для генерации HTML для мультиязычного сервиса?

Первое, что приходит на ум это использовать html/template и структуру с переводом. Что-то вроде

```
type TranslateIndex struct {
    Title string
    Welcome string    
}
translate, _ := Unmarshal(translate_file_russian)
t := template.New("index")
t, _ = t.ParseFiles("templates/index.html")
t.Execute(w, translate)
```

Насколько хорошо/плохо данное решение и есть ли лучше?

Comment: Вроде бы есть gettext

Comment: [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) вроде предлагает готовое решение https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/